# При инициализации проекта возникает ошибка

Tags: node.js

Обычное дело создал папку, закинул туда файлы с кодом, далее npm i. но каждый раз возникает ошибка...

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path E:\IT\Interactive\hooks\node_modules\es5-ext
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command powershell -c  node -e "try{require('./_postinstall')}catch(e){}" || exit 0
npm ERR! ��ப�:1 ����:53
npm ERR! +  node -e "try{require('./_postinstall')}catch(e){}" || exit 0
npm ERR! +                                                     ~~
npm ERR! ���ᥬ� "||" �� ���� �����⨬� ࠧ����⥫�� �����஢ � �⮩ ���ᨨ.
npm ERR!     + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
npm ERR!     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\VerusMiles\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-07T14_33_55_385Z-debug-0.log
```

Я испробовал:
3 версии node 16.15.1 | 18.15.0 | 19.8.1
вводил npm i, npm install
проверил путь папки, все норм

Начинается установка, появляется папка node_modules, потом вылетает ошибка папка node пропадает.
Какие варианты решения есть?

Comment: вот, похожий вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/a/65627596/4496422